# how can we implement push notification using newly created java standalone project in STS?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, push-notification, implementation

Actually I have created a new java project but I am struggling to implement the push notification. I have searched in google, but I am getting the project from spring boot for implementing the push notification. Is that possible to do in java project? If yes, please anyone provide the sample code for doing push notification.